# Google Maps crash reports. dynamite_mapsdynamite

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, firebase-crash-reporting

Facing some crash reports in Firebase Crashlytics. But in manual testing of application there no crashes, only warning. All features working as expected.

Thats example of Firebase crash log:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.br.v()' on a null object reference
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.co.h(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@224312037@22.43.12 (150400-0))
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.o.ba(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@224312037@22.43.12 (150400-0):15)
       at ey.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@224312037@22.43.12 (150400-0):4)
       at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1046)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:2)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzk.onLowMemory(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:2)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzau.onLowMemory(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:1)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onLowMemory(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:1)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onLowMemory(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:1)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performLowMemory(Fragment.java:3223)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchLowMemory(FragmentManager.java:3006)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performLowMemory(Fragment.java:3224)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchLowMemory(FragmentManager.java:3006)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.lambda$new$1$androidx-fragment-app-FragmentManager(FragmentManager.java:454)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.accept(:4)
       at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onTrimMemory(ComponentActivity.java:879)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleTrimMemory(ActivityThread.java:6441)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:257)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.lambda$scheduleTrimMemory$0(ActivityThread.java:1678)
       at android.app.-$$Lambda$ActivityThread$ApplicationThread$tUGFX7CUhzB4Pg5wFd5yeqOnu38.accept(:8)
       at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.doInvoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:278)
       at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.invoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:201)
       at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.OmniFunction.run(OmniFunction.java:97)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1076)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:897)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:828)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1061)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8057)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
```

Example of warning in manual testing:

```
Unable to update local snapshot for com.google.android.libraries.consentverifier#com.app.package, may result in stale flags.
                                                                          java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed: pkg=com.app.package, sha256=[e8173febe247a2e7243253c1ef9ce437fc2d0b4fabffef1ae063e706303f297c], atk=false, ver=224312044.true (go/gsrlt)
                                                                                                        at ait.s(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@224312044@22.43.12 (190400-0):3)
                                                                                                        at ait.get(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@224312044@22.43.12 (190400-0):2)
                                                                                                        at akd.g(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@224312044@22.43.12 (190400-0):2)
                                                                                                        at yj.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@224312044@22.43.12 (190400-0):1)
                                                                                                        at yl.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@224312044@22.43.12 (190400-0):0)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:463)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed: pkg=com.app.package, sha256=[e8173febe247a2e7243253c1ef9ce437fc2d0b4fabffef1ae063e706303f297c], atk=false, ver=224312044.true (go/gsrlt)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3011)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2995)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2978)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2920)
                                                                                                        at ex.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@224312044@22.43.12 (190400-0):2)
                                                                                                        at rm.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@224312044@22.43.12 (190400-0):4)
                                                                                                        at jd.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@224312044@22.43.12 (190400-0):2)
                                                                                                        at kc.t(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@224312044@22.43.12 (190400-0):2)
                                                                                                        at kc.u(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@224312044@22.43.12 (190400-0):3)
                                                                                                        at kc.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@224312044@22.43.12 (190400-0):2)
                                                                                                        at kg.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@224312044@22.43.12 (190400-0):69)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                                                                                                        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

Also exception may contain different version of Play Services.

Updating of `com.google.android.gms:play-services` didn`t help